# Getting window title in Python - the hard way?

Tags: python, linux, x11

I want to check a window title every X seconds in Python - so far no big problem and I found a lot of stuff like xprop.
Now here's the tricky part: when usind xprop -id [id] instead of the pointer thingy I only get 2 or 3 lines like

```
_KDE_NET_WM_USER_CREATION_TIME(CARDINAL) = 24625202
SM_CLIENT_ID(STRING) = "1028c1d320b210000136266856800000015460035"
WM_CLIENT_LEADER(WINDOW): window id # 0x3a00004
```

That's not what I've seen elsewhere and not what I need - so how can I get that title thing? Is this some misconfiguration or am I horribly wrong with everything?

PS: I'm using Fedora 18 btw

Answer (score 0):

When using `xprop -name somewindowname ...` you get all the information.  However, if `somewindowname` is the thing you are trying to find out, that form may not be useful.

Another approach, supposing that the window id is an hexadecimal number (eg, 0x04a27cf6) is to use `wmctrl  -l` and grep for the number.  For example, on my machine (tini) with window 0x04a27cf6 titled "xprop man page",

```
wmctrl  -l | grep 0x04a27cf6
```

produces

```
0x04a27cf6  4 tini xprop man page
```

Note, "wmctrl is a UNIX/Linux command line tool to interact with an EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager", as described at [tomas.styblo.name](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) and in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wmctrl).  Package managers for several linux distributions can install it.

*Edit:* I ran more tests with `xprop` after reading n.m.'s answer.  In tests yesterday, `xprop -id  0x4a27cf7` output one and only one line, `_NET_WM_USER_TIME(CARDINAL) = 440569797`.  It was not a question of “scrolling your terminal way up”.   Unfortunately, I don't have window 0x4a27cf7 available anymore, and now all tests like that seem to be working ok, as indicated in n.m.'s answer.  For example, after the command

```
for i in $(wmctrl -l |tee w-wmctrl | cut -c-10); do xprop -id $i | grep ^WM_NAME; done > w-xprop
```

files `w-wmctrl` and `w-xprop` each have 39 lines in them, and side-by-side comparison via `diff -y w-*|less` without exception shows the same names in both files.

Comment: Ok, this works. But is there someway to stick with "out-of-the-box" tools? I don't want much dependencies. In fact xprop seems to be able to give the information I need, but not with the -id method

Answer (score 0):

You get identical set of properties with `-id` and with a mouse click, *provided you select the same window in both cases*. To get a window ID, use `xwininfo` and click on the window.

The small set of properties you are getting might be simply because the list is big and contains many blank lines. Try scrolling your terminal way up.